# AngularJS set cookies from $resource request and resend them in other requests

Tags: angularjs, phalcon

I'm consuming services from an API coded using Phalcon micro framework, eg api.mydomain.com

I'm consuming the API using AngularJS and I'm performing the requests using the next code:

```
Services.factory('theRequester', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('http://api.mydomain.com/myrequest', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:false}
    });
  }]);
```

I'm receiving the first response correctly, (which sets sessions data in the server side) and it returns this in the headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 22 May 2014 23:05:02 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=105c5ec5df299f758c1ea124d93b109c; path=/; domain=mydomain.com
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.27
```

Now, for each new request I perform to the API I need to send the PHPSESSID cookie, but the problem is that the cookie is not being set after performing the request, and if I set the cookie manually in the browser the cookie is also not send in the other requests I do.

I already did a research and I always read the browser automatically sends the cookies in each request, but is not doing so.

How can I solve both problems?

Thanks

Comment: try setting the withCredentials flag to true in your xhr request.
this is a CORS know issue

Comment: How can I do that using the $resource? I jsut can find stuff about $http :S

Comment: you couls use the $HttpProvider at config time to set that flag, but here is the docs of the $resource service and it talks about this flag in the actions part

Comment: I did this:

return $resource('http://api.mydoamin.com/request', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:false, withCredentials:true}
    });

But is still not setting and not sending the cookies

Comment: i forgot to ask you 1 what browser are to using, 2 is it allowing cookies? 3 the subsequent requests are to the same domain? if so the browser should handle this by it self, you shouldn't have to do anything. if the cookie is not being set maybe you have some restriction on your browser

Comment: I'm using Chrome, If I do the request directly in the browser it all works fine, but the problem is with Angular, which:

1-> Don't set the cookies that comes in the response header
2-> Don't send the cookies (even if I set them manually)

Comment: thats an automatic process, you shouldn't have to do anything. unless you have some other place that cleans your cookies. other thing that could cause this behavior, is if the cookies are set as secure and http_only in wich case you wouldn't see them in the browser and wouldn't be send in requests to non https connections. this 2 settings should be always set for session cookies